# android display large text fit to device width

Tags: android, html, webview, gmail

I have faced a bit trouble with displaying large text in webview. How to implement like gmail?

Here is my webview configuration:

```
    webView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setMailAccountName(getArguments().getString(ExtrasNames.MAIL_ACCOUNT_NAME));
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true); //controls double tab zoom
    webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    webView.setScrollContainer(true);
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(getActivity()), "ScriptToAndroid");
    webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false); //hide default zoom control
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```

Please help me i need to display like a gmail, it is so readable and usefull.

Comment: if added this line_webView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.TEXT_AUTOSIZING);_  it works, i mean the large text will be readable, but if the text is small it is so hard to read, need to zoom out several times. Any idea? If i remove setLoadWithOverviewMode methos small text is ok, large text is over zoomed out

Comment: Have you tried putting `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">` into your html?

Comment: yes, i have already added it